# 16.04 Cannot Access Terminal

Tags: 16.04, command-line, ssh, login, crash

I'm having troubles. . . I cannot access any terminal (though I haven't tried safe mode).  Default terminal, Xterm, UXterm crash in GUI after being clicked.  Ctrl-Alt-F1 Will bring up a terminal login, but after entering credentials, it loops log in instead of giving a prompt.  The ctrl-alt-f1 screen greys out and is barely readable after login prompt shows.

I have tried updating the system.
Rebooting several times.

Recent system changes?  I installed SSH.  Thought to uninstall it to check, but I don't have terminal access.

7.8 G memory
Intel i7-2600 @3.4 x4
AMD Caicos 
64 bit

I'm no power linux user, so forgive me if this is a noob issue.

Thanks

Comment: logged in as another user and guest, and was able to access terminal.  Neither of those accounts have root access, but this is probably a config issue on my account?  Any issues with Ubuntu updates of late?

Comment: Since you've installed SSH can you SSH onto it from another PC?

Comment: default setting is no remote access on ssh.  sftp works fine tho ; /

Comment: You may be able to sftp "clean" copies of the default `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc` from `/etc/skel` - most likely it's one of those (or the equivalent shell config, if you are using some alternate login shell)

Comment: no dice.  was able to import from /etc/skel  additionally, after looking at my bash history, I had recently installed mysecureshell and plexmediaserver.  I don't know if this has anything to do with it, but plexmediaserver, deluge, are not showing files that exist on a partition on another HD.  Disk scan shows OK, and can load files directly from partition.  Possible corruption issue? I'm making a recovery usb now and will keep digging.

Comment: A fun complication, GRUB broke.  Whoot!

Answer (score 0):

Created new root account.
Removed mysecureshell and plexmediaserver

Problem resolved, mostly.  Cannot access terminal through ctl-alt-F1.